# Camera code for Android 2.3

Tags: android, camera

In my android app I've a button it launches the camera everytime when its clicked.

I've coded it to take four images one by one and stores the images in the four imagevies respectively and I've tested it with Android 4.2.

But this fails in Android 2.3. Do I have to change camera code ? I have my code here.

```
btn_Capture.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                         Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);

        }
});

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) { 

    if(data == null)
    {
        Toast.makeText(AddWarranty.this, "Photo not taken", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else{
    Bundle bundle = data.getExtras();
    if(bundle != null){
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST) { 
        photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

        if (image_Card1.getDrawable() == null) {
            image_Card1.setImageBitmap(photo);
        } else {
            if (image_Card2.getDrawable() == null) {
                image_Card2.setImageBitmap(photo);
            } else {
                if (image_Card3.getDrawable() == null) {
                    image_Card3.setImageBitmap(photo);
                } else {
                    if (image_Card4.getDrawable() == null) {
                        image_Card4.setImageBitmap(photo);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        }
```

Comment: you must be getting errors in your error log, please post it .

Comment: Sorry I'm talking about running my app in Android 2.3 mobile phone

Comment: `But this fails in Android 2.3` so what you getting instead of correct output ?

Comment: The application gets stopped unfortunately

Comment: yeah so there must be some description about the problem in error log, why don't you check ??

Comment: Can you tell how to check for error from your mobile phone?

Comment: Simply connect your phone with your computer and run the project from ecipse and yes make sure to enable usb debugging in your phone :)

Comment: Yeah thank you juned, I'm gonna try for sure